# Save UI Image and UI Label to a variable to be brought back later

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uilabel

I need to save what pictures are in the UIImageViews to some variable to bring them back later. The images also have corresponding labels that have a number 1-6.

I have a button that shuffles the images. However, when one person is done with their turn, I want those images saved so that when the next person's turn is over(it would do the same save thing) the original person will see the images seen when they finished their turn. I would like the labels to do the same.

I'm not quite sure how I would. I am temped to just have two different sets of UIimageViews so that I can just have one "hidden" once the turn is over and unhide the other set.

Answer (score 0):

You keep the same image but save the image name as an NSString for later. Then you can load a new image into it:

_yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_yourSavedImageName];

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.
I understand your approach and I am about to try and implement it.
However, I'm not quite sure how to take the image shown in the view get the value of the image's name.
Such as
//Image saved
NSString savedImageName = myImage.image.(imagename?)

Comment: I guess my answer assumes you are setting the image name manually in code. Are you doing this through interface builder? Somehow you'll need that file name.

Comment: Well I have a UIImageView that will display one of 18 images, randomly.
So when I want to save them I have the image on screen but to check the file name, I'm not quite sure how.
I guess I could have an array with all the 18 images and check to see at what index it is? But I'm not quite sure how to set up a Loop that does that.